# CoverStory for iPhone testing?

Tags: iphone, unit-testing, xcode

I'm trying unsuccessfully to get CoverStory working in an iPhone project. Unfortunately XCode build settings and gcc flags are a big mystery to me. :( I've managed to generate .gcno files but the .gcda files don't show. I've added -lgcov as an other linker flag, set both the GCC_GENERATE_TEST_COVERAGE_FILES and GCC_INSTRUMENT_PROGRAM_FLOW_ARCS flags to YES as specified in the documentation but I still have no luck. I also downloaded the fat libgcov.a file from CoverStory's site and included that in my project. I am trying this with the new built in support for iPhone unit tests using a logic unit test bundle. Could this be the cause? Does the app need to run as an application in order to generate these files?
[image]

Answer (score 2):

According to what you have said that you've done, you might be missing the actual coverage part.  To the other linker flags item you need to add -lgcov, and similar to the flow_arcs flag, you need the GCC_GENERATE_TEST_COVERAGE_FILES flag to be yes, so that you can get your .gcov output file.  I'm assuming you know where the file should be, but just for completeness it should be here:

```
${PROJECT_DIR}/build/${PRODUCT_NAME}.build/${CONFIGURATION}-${PLATFORM_NAME}/${PRODUCT_NAME}.build/Objects-normal
```

I have found http://www.cubiclemuses.com/cm/articles/2009/05/14/coverstory-on-the-iphone/ to be a useful resource here.

I'm just getting into this stuff also, so, anyone, feel free to add to my answer.

Comment: Thanx for answering. I did include all of the necessary flags even though I didn't mention. (I'll edit my post for accuracy.) I tried again from a fresh project and still its not working. The instructions at your link leave out the critical step of including libgcov. I downloaded the copy from the coverstory site.

Answer (score 0):

If you're running the tests on the device, you might want to check the solution I found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1945229/how-to-set-up-gcov-for-code-coverage-analysis-in-iphone-sdk/1950527#1950527). It sounds like you're not, but just in case...