# How to setup environment variables for gcov on iPhone

Tags: iphone, code-coverage, gcov, coverstory

I have overcome all problems with setting up `gcov` on my iPhone project but now I am getting the following:

```
profiling:/Users:Cannot create directory
```

Does anyone have any suggestions as to what I might be doing wrong?

I originally setup gcov following Google's instructions which can be found by Googling "UsingCoverStory"

UPDATE:
Okay, so let me clarify what I am trying to do. I have an iPhone app that I trying to test automatically. I am using the `UISpec` framework to drive the GUI. What I really what to know is how much code I am actually covering with my tests. I think that I am really close but I just need to understand how to properly set the environment/compiler variables to fit my project.

Here is a summary of what I have done so far. I first copied my build target, specified the linker flag and a couple of other options as prescribed. (This can be done automatically using an AppleScript created by Google. Instructions and download can be found by Googling "UsingCoverStory") Anyway, I have verified that these settings are being assigned correctly. I set my config to Debug and I am running this on a 3.1.3 Device. When I run the app, it doesn't show anything special in the debugger until I exit the app. At that point I get an error:

```
profiling:/Users:Cannot create directory
profiling:/Users/forbushbl/Documents/TestApp/build/TestApp.build/Debug-iphoneos/TestApp copy.build/Objects-normal/armv6/ApplicationController.gcda:Skip
```

I assume that `GCOV` is trying to write out the `.gcda` files but I'm not quite sure how to tell it where they should be written. I read somewhere that that `GCOV` tries to reproduce the directory structure where the `.gcno` files are stored in my project folder which would make sense as the directory above is where the `.gcno` files are located on my machine. However this is a problem because that structure doesn't exist on the iPhone nor can the device create that structure.

I found another person with the same problem and they said that they had to set an environment variable. [How to set up gcov for code coverage analysis in iPhone SDK?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1945229/how-to-set-up-gcov-for-code-coverage-analysis-in-iphone-sdk)

The `GCOV` documentation says the following:

> For example, if the object file `/user/build/foo.o`  was built with
>   `-fprofile-arcs`, the final executable will try to create the data file `/user/build/foo.gcda` when running on the target system. This will fail
>   if the corresponding directory does not exist and it is unable to
>   create it. This can be overcome by, for example, setting the
>   environment as  `GCOV_PREFIX=/target/run' and `GCOV_PREFIX_STRIP=1'.
>   Such a setting will name the data file `/target/run/build/foo.gcda`.

My question is, how do I set these environment variable on the iPhone? Should I be doing this in my build configuration or within the actual code?

Comment: More detail on the environment variables and how to use them in a generic (not iPhone) context: [Data file relocation to support cross-profiling](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Cross_002dprofiling.html#Cross_002dprofiling)

Answer (score 1):

You should set these variables using setenv in the main.m file of your project:

```
const char *prefix = "GCOV_PREFIX";
const char *prefixValue = [[NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Documents"] cStringUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding]; // This gets the filepath to the app's Documents directory
const char *prefixStrip = "GCOV_PREFIX_STRIP";
const char *prefixStripValue = "1";
setenv(prefix, prefixValue, 1); // This sets an environment variable which tells gcov where to put the .gcda files.
setenv(prefixStrip, prefixStripValue, 1); // This tells gcov to strip the default prefix, and use the filepath that we just declared.
```

Note: Make sure the above code is before:

```
NSAutoreleasePool * pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];
int retVal = UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, nil);
[pool release];    
return retVal;
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to set these env vars in your executable settings. Open up the "executables" branch of your project (in the tree/disclosure view) and then double click on your executable. Under the arguments pane you can set environment variables.